# Can't import first_open event to Google Ads from Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, google-ads-api, firebase-analytics

When importing events from Firebase analytics to Google Ads, I am seeing all other events except for first_open for iOS platform, it's showing for Android though. What could be wrong?
[image: Import view on Google Ads console]

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to solve the problem? I ran into the same one.